# how can I restrict my user to add new drivers depending upon their pricing plan

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, multiple-tables

AGENT DB TABLE

```
agent_id  agent_name company_name
--------  ----------  -----------
1         AAA           XXX
2         BBB           YYY
3         CCC           ZZZ
4         DDD           XYZ
```

DRIVER DB TABLE

```
agent_id  driver_id   driver_name
--------  ----------  -----------
2         1           EEE
2         2           FFF
2         3           GGG
1         4           HHH
3         5           III
3         6           JJJ
```

SUBSCRIPTION DB TABLE

```
agent_id  subscription_id   pricing_plan
--------  --------------    -----------
1         1                 3
2         2                 1
3         3                 0
4         4                 2
```

I have three kind of pricing_plans in my subscription table. Here, I want to control the agent to add new drivers in his account. For example, `agent_id` 2 (BBB) have `pricing_plan` (1). if `pricing_plan` is 1 that specific agent can add 5 drivers only in his account. Then he could not add no more drivers in his account. (after 5th driver)

Another example, `agent_id` 4 (DDD) have `pricing_plan` (2). if `pricing_plan` is 2 that specific agent can add 25 drivers only in his account. Then he could not add no more drivers in his account. (after 25th driver) I want to count the number of drivers depending upon loggedin `agent_id` and `pricing_plan` and do some condition between pricing_plan and number of drivers.

I HAVE TRIED THIS BELOW QUERY

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) `no_of_drivers` , s . *
FROM ta_drivers d, ta_subscription s
WHERE d.agent_id = s.agent_id
AND s.pricing_plan = (
SELECT pricing_plan
FROM ta_subscription
WHERE agent_id = $agent_id )
```

THIS QUERY RETURNS THIS OUTPUT

```
 no_of_drivers    agent_id       pricing_plan
 ------------- --------------    -----------
    1                1                 3
    3                2                 1
    2                3                 0
    0                4                 2
```

I can get the number of drivers of the `agent_id` and I have the `pricing_plan` option too. But, I don't know how to do the condition between these two columns `no_of_drivers` & `pricing_plan` and depending upon the number of drivers & pricing_plan of `agent_id` they cannot add more drivers.

pricing plan 1 => add 5 drivers only

pricing plan 2 => add 25 drivers only

pricing plan 3 => add unlimited drivers

Comment: why php is tagged here?

Comment: Where in the database is the information that pricing plan X allows Y number of drivers? If it's in one of the tables shown here, it's not obvious to me.

Comment: You want that to be displayed in the query ? SOmething as a new column `can add drivers` `yes` or `No` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be pretty trivially done using a [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement. I've put together [an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/483eb/1) that I think answers the question you're ultimately trying to ask.

Comment: Note that you don't really need the subquery; it's just for convenience so I can reference the inner 'case' statements by a column name.

Comment: its working fine. But, it inserts the extra driver. How to stop the insert if its reached the value 0 in remaining_drivers using php if condition?

Comment: Difficult to say, since the question here doesn't discuss your insert statements at all...just check that the remaining_drivers field is > 0 or 'Inf' before doing your insert.